# I m trying to do an apply function over a column in my dataframe, trying to divide the entries in the column Price by 100 using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, data-analysis

```
car_data["Price"]= car_data["Price"].apply(lambda x:x/100))
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


car_data["Price"].dtype
dtype('int32')
```

What is the error in this

Comment: Did you try `car_data["Price"] /= 100`?

Comment: an extra closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

Any syntax error means there is something wrong with the basic rules you have to abide by while writing in a programming language. In your case, there is an abundant Parenthes at the end of the first statement. So it should be:

```
car_data["Price"]= car_data["Price"].apply(lambda x:x/100)
```